# Why is parts of the css hover color getting left over when hovering over links?

Tags: html, css, hover

This is really strange issue, and really makes the links look ugly when part of the hover color is left over. For example I will hover over a link which is white, it will turn a blue color, and on hover out, it turns back to white but with bits of blue color left over.

In the picture below 'hi' is the unhovered link, 'Quotes' shows the left over hover color on a link, & 'Information Theory' is currently being hovered over and thus blue. As you can see the left over color on 'Quotes' is my issue here.

[image]

Also, when hover over this folder icon, there is a bit of white still on one side of the folder when the entire icon should be black on hover.

[image]

**Here is a jsfiddle for this issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/000ge3xv/1/

You can easily reproduce it with the fiddle if you quickly hover over all the links back and forth. Eventually the hover color will get partially 'stuck' on some of the links. I am testing the site in Chrome. I have not noticed the issue in Safari, and have not tested in other browsers.

**UPDATE**

After testing it out more, I think the problem is related to scrolling with a trackpad on a laptop. Since the sidebar is scrollable, if a user is scrolling down the list with the cursor over the links, the hover state gets activated as user scrolls up or down. When the hover state is activating this way, the color tends to get stuck as shown in the photos below. Typically I scroll down the list and then select a link which causes the states to activate while scrolling with a trackpad. So if you are using a laptop (I am using macbook pro trackpad) and scroll to choose a link you should be able to reproduce the bug.)

Here is the html and css I am using:

html

```
<div id="sidebar">
<nav id="cbp-spmenu-s1" class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left unselectable cbp-spmenu-open">
   <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="heading">
         <div class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></div>
         <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newCollectionModal">
            Bookmarks
            <div class="fa fa-plus"></div>
         </span>
      </div>
      <ul class="allList">
         <li><a href="/bookmarks">All Bookmarks</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sortableCollections" class="ui-sortable">
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/GhbYYoo2Qokib8Wkk">Created in IE</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/qFFspAHte7hKmFyuG">Test2</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/34ujRW3wjJrfTsbiG">Physics</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/h2otTW6rmPA3W7Ri3">Food</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/3AiQot9WvrGeMAN5C">Meteor Packages</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/y3Max5ind7N6CTRto">Seelio</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/tScXGq4ZMfSJx2LZL">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="/bookmarks/6ijnJL3GZzLgiaJso">Meteor</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="heading">
         <div class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></div>
         <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newNotepadModal">
            Notepads
            <div class="fa fa-plus"></div>
         </span>
      </div>
      <ul class="allList">
         <li>
            <a id="addFolderToNotepads" href="#">
               <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
               <div class="fa fa-plus">Folder</div>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li><a>All Notes</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sortableNotepads" class="ui-sortable">
         <li>
            <ul class="folder">
               <div class="fa fa-folder-o folder-icon"> Untitled Folder </div>
               <div class="fa fa-cog folder-settings"></div>
               <li><a href="/notepad/ePZFucotx5Zcj8zbk">Solar</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/WXpGG3xyahSX6eA3n">Test Top Rank</a></li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/ijsy5hu7siTZxXYH2">Meteor</a></li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/BDmHQxKmQd7hev2Jw">Created in IE</a></li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/eMnRPNZsYZibZQHRN">Physics</a></li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/M7bfJSjRd9CELT4gn">Again</a></li>
         <li><a href="/notepad/QEDfcoLnH6QuaboEo">Another test</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="/notepads_trash">
               <div class="fa fa-trash-o"></div>
               Trash
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="sidebar-bottom-spacer"></div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS. I all styles are scoped to the #sidebar id

```
#sidebar .cbp-spmenu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(167,177,199,0.95);
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 0 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading:hover {
  color: #567283;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading:hover .fa-plus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading .fa-plus {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading .fa-folder-o {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .heading .fa-folder-o:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .allList {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content ul a {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content ul a:hover {
  color: #567283;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder.open {
  height: auto;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder:hover .fa-cog {
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder .fa {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder .fa:hover {
  color: #567283;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder .fa-cog {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder .fa-cog:hover {
  color: #567283;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .folder li {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu .sidebar-content .sidebar-bottom-spacer {
  height: 70px;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu.cbp-spmenu-left {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

#sidebar .cbp-spmenu.cbp-spmenu-left.cbp-spmenu-open {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Im unable to replicate this issue in Safari, OSX Mavericks

Comment: Chrome 37 on Windows here, and your jsFiddle looks fine.

Comment: hmm, sometimes it get stuck right away, and sometimes it takes a bit of hovering to reproduce... For me it is consistently happening and happens quite often. I am using Chrome 37 on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: no problem with FF and Chrome Windows7, nor FF and Chromium Ubuntu

Comment: I updated the question, as I tracked found out some more information about the bug. It is related to scrolling with a trackpad and activating the hover states while scrolling.

Comment: Anyone able to test with trackpad?

Comment: I tested with a trackpad and didn't seem to have any issues. It could just be your machine or browser not picking up the hover states quick enough.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you test with a trackpad, you should two finger scroll while the cursor is over the links. So the cursor does not move, the whole sidebar just scrolls. The computer I am using is new and powerful so I don't think it is due to computer performance. It could just be Chrome on a Mac?

Comment: WFM on Chrome on MacBook Pro Mavericks. Put mouse over sidebar (tried both on & off a link), used two-finger scroll.
Have you tried rebooting? Also, disable any Chrome extensions, clear the browser cache, and do some Mac Maintenance. https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16790/maintenance

Comment: It is a local problem I think..

Comment: I just tried it again on my app, and I now with the new Chrome 38 it does not do it anymore! This can be considered resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your bug I've tried all my browsers under Windows 8.1 I think that this bug is in your browser only :)

Comment: It is, and I noticed that in Chrome 38 it doesn't even happen on my computer anymore.